Error calling event locally in serverless
i am getting this error while invoke even in serverless
   ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                                                                     │
   │   ANY | http://0.0.0.0:3000/dev/{proxy*}                            │
   │   POST | http://0.0.0.0:3000/2015-03-31/functions/api/invocations   │
   │                                                                     │
   └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Server ready: http://0.0.0.0:3000 


ANY /dev/%7Bproxy*%7D (λ: api)
✖ Unhandled exception in handler 'api'.
✖ ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.go' (ENOENT)
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.go'
✖ ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.go'


ANY /dev/ping (λ: api)
✖ Unhandled exception in handler 'api'.
✖ ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.go' (ENOENT)
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.go'
✖ ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.go'

but all is working if i deploy
my serverless.yml
service: myapi

frameworkVersion: ">=4.1.19"

plugins:
  - serverless-offline

provider:
  name: aws
  region: eu-north-1
  runtime: go1.x
  stage: ${opt:stage}

package:
  patterns:
    - '!*/**'
    - bin/main

functions:
  api:
    handler: bin/main
    events:
      - http:
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: ANY
          cors: true

